# Run a C++ Program from Django Framework

Tags: c++, python, django

I need to run a C++ Program from Django Framework. In a sense, I get inputs from UI in views.py . Once I have these inputs, I need to process the input using my C++ program and use those results. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 10):

Compile that C++ program to executable and call with [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module from python

Answer (score 1):

You can use swig to create a C++ module that can be imported in python.
An alternative is boost::python (but personnaly, I prefer swig).

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this would be to use [os.popen](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.popen). Assuming your C++ executable is in the system wide path and is named `mycpp`, you would do something like:

```
results = os.popen('mycpp %s' % user_input).read()
```

However, this could get computationally expensive real fast if you're invoking this command often 'cause `os.popen` basically forks off a subprocess. Also, as noted in the docs, it's been deprecated since Python 2.6 so proceed with caution.

Comment: Not only is it deprecated, there's no reason to use it.  The exact same functionality is available in the `subprocess` module, as mentioned in S.Mark's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are on *nix, compile your C++ program and store it somewhere on your system, say /home/rishabh/myexe.

Now from your django app call the executable using commands module:

```
import commands

status, res = commands.getstatusoutput("/home/rishabh/myexe")

# status contains process status (0 for success, non-zero for unsuccesful termination) and res contains the output of the process
```